# Remove references to old windows partition long after migrating to ssd?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, migration

A **few years ago, I migrated my windows 10 installation from an HDD to an SSD** (with Aomei Partition Assistant if I recall correctly). The old HDD remained connected as a data drive. All seemed fine a the time. *Disk Management* showed (and still does) all drive letters where I expect(ed) them (i.e. C on the SSD and the E data partition still on the HDD, and no drive letter on the old windows partition on the HDD).

However, upon checking now why my HDD sometimes spins up with resmon, *resmon* shows files being accessed by "*System*" on "*\Device\HarddiskVolume4*", which according to "*System Information Viewer*" corresponds to the old Windows partition on the HDD.

The questions are:

- how is this partition still referenced?
- so long after migration, can these references to the old partition on the HDD still be safely removed?
- if so, how?

Comment: If the disk is still online, try to disable content search. See [this link](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/08/10/manage-windows-10-search-indexing/).

Comment: Thank you for the help. The disk is still online, but the volume (old windows partition) should not be. How do I disable content indexing on a partition that has no drive letter assigned? I'd rather not disable it as a whole. Or is this meant more as a temporary diagnostic technique rather than as permanent solution?

Comment: Oh okay, you can disable indexing of contents of a volume that is not mounted by getting to its properties through disk management. If that doesn't help, I'll try assigning it a drive letter, just to be able to select the drive as an exclusion for windows search indexing.

Comment: Without a drive letter, the disk shouldn't be accessed by Windows. It's probably being woken up by a status-query.